# Evaluate $\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x + \cos x}\,\text{d}x$.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how to take this indefinite integral:

$$ \int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x + \cos x}\,\text{d}x.$$

I tried simplifying and rearranging it, and this is the best I got:
$$\int\frac{1}{\tan x + 1 }\,\text{d}x.$$

But I still can't figure out how to integrate from there. I know that it's integrable, as [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427egqgdbv6t5c) indicates that the integral is $ \frac{1}{2}\big(x+\ln{(\sin x + \cos x)}\big)+C$, but I can't figure out the steps to deriving it. Does anyone know how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: This is basically the same as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180744/compute-int-frac-sinx-sinx-cosx-mathrm-dx). (To be more precise, if you know one of the two integrals, it is easy to calculate the other one and vice versa.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $I=\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx$ and $J=\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx$.

Then $I+J=\int\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx=x+C_1$ and $I-J=\int\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx=\ln |\sin x+\cos x|+C_2$.

Hence $I=\frac{1}{2}((I+J)+(I-J))=\frac{1}{2}(x+\ln |\sin x+\cos x|)+C$.

Comment: This is very elegant in that it requires no substitutions.

Comment: @user54147 You are using a substitution, $u = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$ in the end

Answer (score 5):

A **general** (but not necessarily efficient) tool is the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $t=\tan(x/2)$.

Then $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, $\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, and $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}$. Do the substitution. We end up needing the  following ugly integral:
$$\int \frac{2(1-t^2)}{(1+2t-t^2)(1+t^2)}\,dt.$$
We are integraing a rational function, and it can be done using partial fractions. But it takes some work.

The same idea works in principle for any rational function of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that
$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
Therefore
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}dx$$
Now let $x+\frac{\pi}{4}=t$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\cos \left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\sin t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sin t + \cos t}{\sin t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\left(t+\ln {\left|\sin t\right|}\right)+C_1\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}+\ln {\left|\sin x+\cos x\right|}\right)+C_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\ln {\left|\sin x+\cos x\right|}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+ \tan x} \ dx $

$ \displaystyle = \int \frac{1}{1+u} \frac{1}{1+u^{2}} \ du$ (let $u = \tan x$)

$ \displaystyle =  \frac{1}{2} \int \left( \frac{1}{1+u} + \frac{1-u}{1+u^{2}} \right) \ du$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2} \int \left( \frac{1}{1+u}  - \frac{u}{1+u^{2}} + \frac{1}{1+u^{2}} \right) \ du $

$ \displaystyle =\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(1+u) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+u^{2}) + \arctan u \right) + C$

$ \displaystyle =\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(1+u) - \ln(\sqrt{1+u^{2}}) + \arctan u \right) + C$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln(1+\tan x) - \ln (\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}x}) + x \right) + C$

$  \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln(1+\tan x) - \ln (\sec x) + x \right) + C$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \ln \big(\frac{1+ \tan x}{\sec x}\big)  + x \Big) + C$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln (\cos x + \sin x ) + x \right) + C $