# $\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)} dt$ and $\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)} dt$

Tags: integration

Let $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, $I(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)} dt$ and $J(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)} dt$ .

The aim of the exercise is to calculate $I(x)$ and $J(x)$.

Fisrt of all, we see that $I(x)+J(x)=x$.

If I do "$u=\pi/2 -t$", I get (since $\sin(\pi/2-y) = \cos(y)$): $I(x) = \int_{\pi/2-x}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(u)+\sin(u)}du = J(\pi/2) - J(x)$. And so $I(x)+J(x)= J(\pi/2)$... Which is impossible beacause $J(\pi/2)$ doesn't depend of $x$.

I don't see where my computations fails...

Comment: It's $J(\pi/2) - J(\pi/2-x)$.

Comment: Another post about the same integral (but indeterminate): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180744/compute-int-frac-sinx-sinx-cosx-mathrm-dx