# Integration Tips and Tricks

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Im looking for Tips and Tricks for integration. I know all the basic techniques (substitution, completing the square, parts etc.) I'm mainly interested in dealing with logs in the denominator and dealing with trig terms both above and below (such as lesser known identities etc.
For instance there are lots of nice techniques for sinx/sinx + cosx. Is there any general technique that can be applied across a wide range of integrals which don't fall under the standard techniques

Comment: Granted it's quite similar but I'm looking more specifically into logs of which I couldn't find any reference in above thread.

Comment: For the particular example in your post, you may want to look over here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180744/compute-int-frac-sinx-sinx-cosx-mathrm-dx/318212#318212 Otherwise, I think that practice and "expose yourself" to others showing their approach to a particular integral problem, is the way. You then get that "Hey, I didn't know it could be done this way" feeling. That happened to me quite a lot, in part because of sharing ideas on this site