# Integral of $\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

> The questions defines $$I=\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin x +\cos x}dx\;\;J=\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x +\cos x}dx$$
>   It asked me to find $I+J$ and $J-I$ which I have done and I will show below but now I need to find the integral shown below and I'm unsure on what to do.
>   $$\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$$

I have found that:
$$I+J = x+c$$
$$J-I=\ln{|\cos x +\sin x|} +c$$

But now i'm unsure on how to find just $I$

Comment: If you know what $J-I$ is, you know what $I-J$ is. Try adding $I-J$ and $I+J$ together.

Comment: Another post about the same integral: [Compute $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180744).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have is:
$$I+J=x+C$$
$$I-J=-\ln|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|+C$$
so:
$$2I=x-\ln|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|+C$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

Consider the following system of equations :

$$\begin{cases} J+I = x+c \\ J - I = \ln|\cos x + \sin x | + c\end{cases}$$

See an easy way out for $I$ ?